# How to split a string by char 0 / byte 0 / 0x00 / \u0000 in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, null, split, char

How do I split a string by char 0 / byte 0 / 0x00 / \u0000 in flash actionscript 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K solved if anyone needs help with this turns out you can just do this

```
var packets:Array = data.split("\x00");
```